# To load a log table with start date, end date and proc progress of a package in oracle

Tags: oracle, logging, plsql, package, procedure

I have a table by name AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX loaded through a plsql package.

I have a log table MD_RUNS_STEP with the below structure:

```
STEP_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER        
RUN_TYPE               VARCHAR2(10)  
RUN_START              DATE          
RUN_END                DATE          
RUN_SUCCESS            NUMBER        
USERNAME               VARCHAR2(30)  
RUN_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER        
RUN_ROLLBACK           NUMBER        
STEP_ID_PREV           NUMBER        
SYSID                  VARCHAR2(9)   
PROGRESS               VARCHAR2(500) 
STAT_RECS              NUMBER        
STAT_CPU               NUMBER        
STAT_TIME              NUMBER        
STAT_SEQ_READ          NUMBER        
STAT_SCT_READ          NUMBER
```

Now I need to load this log table with the above values when my package is being executed.
How can this be done? can anyone please help me I have no idea about how it works as I am new to oracle.

Looking forward for the reply.

Thank you

Comment: Adding rows to a table is done using the `INSERT` command. What exactly is your question.

Comment: @Deepthi:as `a_horse_with_no_name` mentioned ,you can insert into `MD_RUNS_STEP` after loading your `AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX`.Or if you want to log after every insert then use the trigger on that table .

Answer (score 2):

There is no Oracle specific way/setting of automatically populating this log table. Since It is specific to your application, once you understand what these columns mean, you can add code to your pl/sql procedure to get the logs as needed. Some of the columns are straightforward and this is usually how the code looks.

Let us say your current procedure current looks something like this..

```
create or replace procedure p_INS_AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX
as
BEGIN
  insert into p_INS_AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX(.....) values (.....);
  update p_INS_AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX set... where ...;
  commit;
END;
/
```

Let's take some log columns..(STEP_ID, RUN_START, RUN_END , RUN_SUCCESS).
Your code would look something like this after the change

```
create or replace procedure p_INS_AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX
as
  procedure add_new_log (i_step_id) is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin
    insert into MD_RUNS_STEP (i_step_id, run_start) 
        values (i_step_id, sysdate);
     commit;
  end;

  procedure update_status (i_step_id, i_status) 
  .....
  end;

  v_step_id number;

BEGIN

  select run_step_id_seq.nextval into v_step_id from dual;

  add_new_log(v_step_id);

  insert into p_INS_AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX(.....) values (.....);
  update p_INS_AN_REMEDIATION_MATRIX set... where ...;
  commit;

  update_status(i_step_id,'SUCCESS'); --will set the load finish time as well.

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     update_status(i_step_id,'FAILURE');  
     --RAISE, SEND ERROR EMAIL Based on your logic.
END;
/
```

as @DCookie pointed out (+1) , Autonomous transaction is a perfect use-case for logging like this. Your main transaction is not impacted and you can, at any point, see the latest up-to-date status of the run.

*Usually, you might have existing packages that does all this updates and you'll probably need to just call these APIs. Ask around or look at one the currently running loads.*

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to perform periodic inserts into this table as your package is executing, and need the ability to see the progress from another session?

If so, you might look into the [PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm) statement. Put your insert statement into a function defined with this PRAGMA in it, and you can commit your insert independent of your package. Call your function as needed in your package.